# Application does not start?

Tags: android, android-activity

This is a weird bug I have come across where my activity or say application does not start. As soon as I touch icon of my app and I press lock button , then when i unlocked it I can not see my application opened and moreover it is not in the active application status also. As per the flow of application  runs it should get opened behind or atleast can be seen in Active Application status? 
Is there any way to resolve it.

Comment: Have you tried this with any other applications?

Comment: What if you give it time to load, and the press lock button? Are you sure the android just isnt loading it due to cancelling the load process. It might be natural. When you lock a phone it goes to pause status, but from what it sounds like, yours hasnt got to create yet, so getting to onpause is impossible.

Comment: Run it in debug mode. as suggested below.  Don't even think about coding android without becoming familar with the debugger. Place a breakpoing in onCreate, onPause etc and see whats really happening.

Comment: You are wasting your time if you don't get the debugger going at once. If you have questions about debugger just ask.

Comment: @CodeDroid - Thanks dude, i tried to debug it was because I was running thread on my splashscreen and i was closing it if back key pressed .. I found the bug thanks ...

Comment: @Doomsknight : THanks bro !! I found the problem .. I thought it was unusual android issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can trace your code from adb or find tools in android sdk tools folder finder the tool to get the logs